# How to test Nymi Unlock App for Mac?

Tags: macos

I am trying to test the `Nymi band` for unlocking the device using my ECG. I successfully stored my ECG in the `Nymi band` and I am using Nymi Companion App to connect the band to Mac. Nymi also launched the unlock app to unlock the device ,but I tried everything I could,but the nymi band doesn't unlock the device for me. Can anyone please tell me the correct procedure that needs to be followed to unlock the device?

I even looked into their website for the proper documentation ,but they haven't provided any regarding the unlock app. (I couldn't add the tag Nymi as I don't have much reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After activating the nymi band with Mac NCA, I just need to press enter instead of typing the password. The nymi band will take care of the rest.